# Looking for good guide on how to deploy and verify source code of Smart Contract using Truffle/Remix

Tags: truffle, remix, contract-deployment, verify, contract-verification

Can't really find good guides on how to deploy and verify smart contracts to testnetwork Ropsten. Would like to deploy multifile smart contracts including libraries.
Are there any good HowTos already? Would highly appreciate guides for truffle and also for Remix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [`truffle-plugin-verify`](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify) to automate Truffle contract verification on Etherscan. This has made the process much easier. 
I explain the usage of this plugin in my article [Automatically verify Truffle smart contracts on Etherscan](https://kalis.me/check-events-solidity-smart-contract-test-truffle/).